# Unable to import azure.functions in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, azure-functions

I am trying to create python based 'Function Apps' in Azure, but struggling with the very first step on importing azure.functions. Even the default code that is created (when a new Function App is created using Azure Portal) will have this line of code: `import azure.functions as func`

When I copy the code to Pycharm i get errors depending on whether i choose Conda or direct python.exe interpreter. When i do NOT use Conda i get below msg:

- Starting with v5.0.0, the 'azure' meta-package is deprecated and
  cannot be installed anymore. Please install the service specific
  packages prefixed by `azure` needed for your application.  .... A
  more comprehensive discussion of the rationale for this decision can
  be found in the following issue:
  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10646

If i use Conda env i get below msg:

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

- Specifications:

  - azure -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

  Your python: python=3.7

  If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version
  you've asked for. When python appears to the right, that indicates
  that the thing on the left is somehow not available for the python
  version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not change your
  python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly
  specify that.

Given that azure.functions is the core module i am sure there is something else at wrong here, but not able to figure out.

Some of the responses for similar issues indicated to install it via pip command (pip install azure==4.0.0). I am able to run this cmd successfully on my windows10 laptop, but Pycharm still says no module found.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For the no module found error, please ensure that the modules are installed at the PyCharm end. You would need the Azure-Functions module.

```
File> Settings> Project :YOUR_PROJECT_NAME > Project Interpreter
```

[image]

If you did not find the azure-functions module.
Click on the '+' icon that is visible in the same window.

Add Azure-Functions module in the subsequent Available Packages Window like below. Click on the **Install Package**

[image]
Close the windows and try importing **azure.functions**

```
import azure.functions
```

**Alternatively** you can install the Azure Functions through the pip command :

> https://pypi.org/project/azure-functions/

```
pip install azure-functions
```

**Additional Information :**

> https://pypi.org/project/azure/4.0.0/

Reading through the documentation, it appears like the azure functions is not included in the Azure Module. They include only the below.

- azure-mgmt v4.x
- azure-applicationinsights v0.1.x
- azure-batch v4.x
- azure-cosmosb-table v1.x
- azure-datalake-store v0.0.x
- azure-eventgrid v1.x
- azure-graphrbac v0.40.x
- azure-keyvault v1.x
- azure-loganalytics v0.1.x
- azure-servicebus v0.21.x
- azure-servicefabric v6.3.0.0
- azure-servicemanagement-legacy v0.20.x
- azure-storage-blob v1.x
- azure-storage-queue v1.x
- azure-storage-file v1.x

**Update for Conda interpreter:**

When I used the Conda interpreter.

```
File> Settings> Project :YOUR_PROJECT_NAME > Project Interpreter
```

I unselected/Unclicked the "Use Conda Package Manager" (green circle - Conda Icon) which is on the right Project Interpreter Window - Click on it to unselect it. When you unselect it, there will be no highlight behind the icon.

[image]

Now I clicked on the add('+' icon) button and searched for the azure-functions, installed the same - Above mentioned steps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Interestingly, when i change the interpreter from conda to python.exe, i now see azure packages that i am able to add(earlier didnt). If i choose Conda they dont appear even after i open the Conda prompt and do pip install azure-functions (and the cmd response says its succesfully installed). I now have this working (but not for conda)

Comment: @mgn - I unselected the "Use Conda Package Manager" and tried adding it. I was able to add the azure functions. I have updated my answer, please check for more information.