# cant resolve import azure.functions using anaconda python 3.9 on visual code

Tags: python-3.x, azure, visual-studio-code, anaconda, azure-functions

Im trying to follow the "azure functions with python" tutorial on microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python.

The first line

import azure.functions as func

always gets flagged as "cannot be resolved (reportMissingImports)"
I'm running this on Visual Code v 1.66.2 and using python 3.9.7 anaconda package on Windows 10. I saw that
[Unable to import azure.functions in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743398/unable-to-import-azure-functions-in-pycharm)
had a virtually identical issue (using pycharm) but that solution doesn't work for me.
I did try to pip install azure-functions, but its (apparently) only for an older python version. The Microsoft channel on Anaconda lists a lot of Azure packages but not the azure-functions.
The tutorial really doesn't mention doing anything extreme. I had no issue with C# azure function tutorial and was expecting it be the same.
What is the reason I cannot find this package ?

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from our end we could able to create azure function with required python modules being installed after creating a virtual environment. Here are few steps that are required while creation of python Azure function.

1. Make sure Azure function Core tools has been installed.
2. Make sure you have any of Python 3.7.x or 3.6.x or 3.8.x interpreters installed So while creating by selecting the interpreter a **virtual environment** gets created.

   [image]
3. Select a template and provide a name to it.

   [image]
4. Select Authorisation levels and >> Open in new window

   [image]
   [image]
5. After creating, Below will be the file structure of your Application

   [image]

After following the above steps we could able to create an azure function which as all the required modules installed. Additionally you can check requirements.txt file to know what modules have been installed.

**RESULTS:**

Without a virtual environment.

[image]

With a virtual environment.

[image]

For more information you can refer [How To Create Azure Functions In Python](https://azurelessons.com/azure-functions-in-python/#:%7E:text=How%20To%20Create%20Azure%20Functions%20In%20Python%201,stack%20and%20the%20region%20for%20your%20resource.%20)

Comment: thanks, I was not paying attention to the virtual environment need. That got me going in the right direction,

Comment: also note, I had to added ..\Anaconda3\Library\bin to my PATH System Environment Variable. I was getting an SSL error on pip and others have recommended this.

Answer (score 0):

Tried many of the answers proposed and I am not sure what finally fixed it for me, I think it has to do with .venv

I installed the Azure Functions Core Tools here

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#installing

As when running debug it asked me to. This then installed azure-functions again when I ran debug (F5). After that, it worked.